# Ping TimeToLive - just get back number

Tags: powershell

when I do this:

```
$pinging = Get-WmiObject win32_pingstatus -Filter "Address='localhost'" | Select-Object TimeToLive
```

I get back:

```
@{TimeToLive=128}
```

How do I just get the number out and not the @ thing around it?

I need it as I call it later in the below...which is erroring I think becuase it is not just looking at the number only:

```
Switch($pinging)
{
    {$_ -le 128} 
        {return "This is a Windows Server"; break}
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot compare "@{TimeToLive=128}" to "128" because the objects are not the same type or the object "@{TimeToLive=128}" does not implement "IComparable"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

Either use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter in your `Select-Object`

```
> $result = Get-WmiObject win32_pingstatus -Filter "Address='localhost'" | Select-Object -expandproperty TimeToLive
> $result
128
```

Or access the property directly on the variable you assign the object to

```
> $result = Get-WmiObject win32_pingstatus -Filter "Address='localhost'" | Select-Object TimeToLive
> $result.TimeToLive
128
```

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! Thanks a lot!